# Como mapear la base de datos con EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core

estoy usando un proyecto de API con EntityFrameworkCore, y requiero generar el modelo de la base, para esto estoy utilizando comandos de Scaffold en consola de nuget, pero no consigo que reconozca la sintaxis. Desde luego la base está local y disponible.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me da la sensación que el error es porque no puede compilar efectivamente el proyecto. Veo en la imagen que hay una referencia que no está aclarada. Específicamente en `using (NegociosApiContext db = new NegociosApiContext())`
Me imagino que es la clase de la base de datos. ¿Porque primero no haces el Scaffold y luego haces la referencia?

Comment: Gracias amigo, de hecho así lo hice, la razón del porque se muestra esas líneas es porque ya tenía mi contexto generado, pero tuve que migrar de servidor. Tu comentarios de compilación fue certero, comentando esas instancias anteriores y volviendo a ejecutar se resolvió